What is this IC? KA=7F 9A1
I am trying to find what IC is this and its datasheet but I can't find it anywhere.
KA=7F 9A1



It's a Richtek RT6226A DC-DC step-down converter.
The datasheet lists the marking codes, with KA= being the part number identifier and the rest being lot and date codes.


Image Source
The weird footprint also matches the visible pad positions in your post.
